# Why avatar_url discord.py doesn't work when I host the bot in heroku?

Tags: heroku, discord.py

So, I was making a embed creator bot, and for the avatar icon in the author and the footer I used member.avatar_url.

But when I uploaded the bot to heroku I noticed that the question that asked you to say if you wanted to put an author or not, wasn't working and there was stopping the wait for process.

In the requirements file I put the link to the github repository of discord.py.

am I missing something that I should include in that file in order to make the mehthod work?

Sorry for mi english, I'm a spanish teenager and I'm not using the traductor for writing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing code dependant on a version and using a different version while hosting. `User.avatar_url` is only available on versions lesser discord.py v2.0.
Discord v2.0 uses `User.avatar.url`.

You can find the docs in https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/

As there is no proper migrating guide for v2.0 you can find some major changes on https://discord.gg/r3sSKJJ (Discord's official server).

Comment: Oh god, thank you so much man. Now I can now finish my bot :D